# How can I release a program with a database?

Tags: c#, database, release

I just finished writing a large program that uses a pretty large database file. In the past, when I finished writing programs, I just uploaded the .exe file to my website and sent the link to whoever wanted to use it, but now there's also a database file to include..

Is there a way to "wrap" the database file in the .exe? If not, how can I release my program so that the user only has to download one file? I've never created an installer, nor do I really know how.. I've only ever just uploaded .exe files :).

Any help would be appreciated. Excuse my inexperience :P.

The program is programmed in C#, and the database file is in .mdf format (I am running SQL Server 2008). I'd be happy to provide any more details. :)

Comment: You are also going to have to deploy SQL Server on the user's machine.  That requires a license first of all.  And is pretty impactful, do consider aiming lower with SQL Compact or SQLite.  Express deployment details are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264562%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of bundling the entire database, you should make the application know how to create the database. A simple way is to create a script for the entire database in SQL Server Management Studio. Then include the script (probably after you've made some adjustments to it) in the exe file as a resource file.

A better approach than rolling your own solution is to use a data access framework such as EF Code First with Migrations that has database creation and upgrade support built oin.

Answer (score 1):

You can make simple setups from visual studio (Create new setup project). If you need more advanced features, have a look at [Windows Xml installer](http://wix.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You can include the free [Sql Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx) so your users don't have to buy a license of SQL server.  If you want to go through the effort of building an .msi installer, I believe you can do SQL-server - specific actions.

On the other hand, if you have a small amount of data, you might consider using the filtering features of [Dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instead of relying on SQL server.

**Edit:** Microsoft has a new [SqlServer 2012 LocalDB](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237665) that might be interesting:

> New to the SQL Server® Express family, LocalDB is a lightweight
>   version of Express that has the same programmability features, yet
>   runs in user mode and has a fast, zero-configuration installation and
>   short list of pre-requisites. Use this if you need a simple way to
>   create and work with databases from code. It can be bundled with
>   Visual Studio, other Database Development tools or embedded with an
>   application that needs local databases.

(excerpt from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065))